# How to output a mixture of data from 2 mySQL tables when joined columns have similar names?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

What I want to achieve is to show all the published articles and all the published questions of a specific `user_id` in one loop ordered by timestamp. In simple words, to show everything mixing articles and questions.

My database structure is as below, and I have put also the profiles table.

My wrong sql query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles
JOIN questions ON articles.user_id = questions.user_id
WHERE articles.user_id =  '38'
AND questions.user_id =  '38'
AND questions.publish =  '1'
AND articles.publish =  '1'
ORDER BY questions.timestamp DESC
```

Articles table

```
id
publish
user_id
user_name
article_title
article_content
article_category
timestamp
```

Questions table

```
id
publish
user_id
user_name
question_title
question_content
question_category
timestamp
```

Profiles

```
user_id
```

Comment: Use `UNION`, not `JOIN`.

Comment: This question has been answered many times. Look for "alias"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a join, an outer join will get all matching records from both table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles
FULL OUTER JOIN questions ON articles.user_id = questions.user_id
WHERE articles.user_id =  '38'
ORDER BY questions.timestamp DESC
```